# ASP.NET MVC 4.0 Bundles with Multiple Absolute URLs for Styles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle, asp.net-optimization

I have some of my application "**Styles**" and "**Scripts**" are referred from different environment applications.

1. local-sites are referring from `http://localhost:123/mystyles/default.css`
2. Dev site is referring from `http://mydev.com/mystyles/default.css`
3. prod site is referring from `http://prod.com/mystyles/default.css`

I tried to tweak a little with **cdn** on **bundles** like below, but it didn't help.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Clear();
            bundles.ResetAll();

            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
            bundles.UseCdn = true;

            if (HttpRuntime.BinDirectory.Contains("local"))
                cdnHost = "http://localhost:123/";
            else if(condition)
                cdnHost = "http://mydev.com/";
            else
                cdnHost = "http://prod.com/";

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/HRO/jquery/ui/css", cdnHost)
                .Include("~/css/jQuery/hro-0079c1/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/HRO/jquery/ui/css", cdnHost)
               .Include("~/css/jQuery/hro-0079c1/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/HRO/base/css", cdnHost)
               .Include("~/css/base.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/HRO/reset/css", cdnHost)
               .Include("~/css/reset.css"));
        }
```

But this doesn't work. when I call these bundles as below

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/HRO/jquery/ui/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/HRO/base/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/HRO/reset/css")
```

I tried to debug the RegisterBundles(), looks like it is not creating those items with cdn url.

Is this a right way to create a absolute css URL for bundles?
Am I missing anything here?
Is there a better way to debug my RegisterBundles()?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Dismissile I have updated my question. please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set both EnableOptimizations and EnableCDN to true for the cdn urls to be used.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a matter of getting absolute url in bundle then you can go for this.

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IHtmlString RenderScript(this UrlHelper helper, params string[] paths)
        {
            string scripts = System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(paths).ToHtmlString();
            string hostName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;
            string replaced = Regex.Replace(scripts, "src=\"/", "src=\"" + hostName + "/", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return new HtmlString(replaced);
        }
    }
```

This will basically take the bahvior from Scripts.Render and then apply absolute urls to it. Then in the view you have to write

```
  @Url.RenderScript("~/bundles/jquery")
```

instead of

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Enjoy coding!!...

Answer (score 1):

`Scripts` and `Styles` from `System.Web.Optimization`
Supports `RenderFormat`method that can be used in the following way:

```
@{
    var hostName = "www.example.com";
    var styleFormat = "<link href=\"" + hostName+ "{0}\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/>";
}


@Styles.RenderFormat(styleFormat, "~/styles/vendor")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try for example, some like this:

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/HRO/jquery/ui/css","http://mydev.com/css/jQuery/hro-0079c1/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css"));

well I could do. What I could do is to group more than one style in one bundle.

good luck!